# Add combo-box in windows form grid view by using LINQ query

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I'm trying to add the combo Box to the datagrid View by using LINQ query, also i am not using adopters .

```
  var record = from x in dc.GetTable<Detail>()
                           where x.RaisedBy ==  Global.Username
                           orderby x.Datetime descending
                            select new
                            {
                                x.id,
                                x.Name,
                                x.Contact,
                                x.Segment,
                                x.Datetime,
                                x.RaisedBy
                            };



               gvRecord.DataSource = record;
```

Comment: and what the problem?

Comment: Do you have some exception or error code ?

Comment: Add `.ToList()`

Comment: I don't know how can i call the combobox in gridview by using LINQ method , the code which i used in top this is Linq query to call the data in gridview but i don't know how can i  place the combobox in gridview  .

Comment: Exception : Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.                                                                                                                                  
             var record = from x in dc.GetTable<Detail>()   where x.RaisedBy ==  Global.Username orderby x.Datetime descending   select new{  x.id,    x.Name, x.Contact, x.Segment, x.Datetime, x.RaisedBy } Contact.DataSource = dc.Details.ToString();gvRecord.DataSource = record;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var details = (from x in dc.Details
                       select x).ToList();
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Contact";
        comboBox1.DataSource = details;


        try
        {

            var combocolumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            combocolumn.ValueMember = "Contact";// Column name
            combocolumn.DataSource = details;//Convert.ToString(combocolumn).ToList(); //new string[] {"1","2" };// dc.Details; 

            gvRecord.Columns.Add(combocolumn);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
        }




    }
```